# If column having dates in multiple format, Get last date of month for specific date format

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame having two columns (SEQ - Integer, MAIN_DATE - Date) as:

[image]

Now I want to add a column based on the condition that if the format of MAIN_DATE is "MMM-YYYY" then it should be converted to Last day of the month and new data frame should look like this:

[image]

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spark's [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#when(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)/[`otherwise`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#otherwise(value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) methods in order to operate differently for each different date format of the `MAIN_DATE` column.

More specifically, you can simply match the `MMM-yyyy` date format values of the column based on the field's String length (since we know that those values we always have **8 characters**) as a condition in `when` and then:

1. use [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#to_date(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fmt:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to convert the String value to a valid date based on a format we give as an argument, and
2. use [`last_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#last_day(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to get the last day of the month each curry date in `MAIN_DATE` is referring to.

As for the "regular" rows with the `dd-MMM-yyyy` date format, just a `to_date` conversion would be sufficient within the `otherwise` method.

After that, all there's left to do is to convert the dates back to the desired `dd-MMM-yyyy` format (because `to_date` converts a given date to the `yyyy-MM-dd` format).

This is the solution in **Scala** (split in into two `withColumns` to make it more readable, instead of an one-liner):

```
df.withColumn("END_DATE",
            when(length(col("MAIN_DATE")).equalTo(8), last_day(to_date(col("MAIN_DATE"), "MMM-yyyy")))
              .otherwise(to_date(col("MAIN_DATE"), "dd-MMM-yyyy")))
.withColumn("END_DATE", date_format(col("END_DATE"), "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

This is what the resulting `df` DataFrame will look like:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+
|SEQ|  MAIN_DATE|   END_DATE|
+---+-----------+-----------+
|  1|16-JAN-2020|16-Jan-2020|
|  2|   FEB-2017|28-Feb-2017|
+---+-----------+-----------+
```